# loading DB driver in Global.beforeStart

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, playframework, ebean

I want to implement some DB cleanup at each startup (full schema deletion and recreation while in dev-enviroment).

I'm doing it in Global.beforeStart. And because it's literally **before start** I need to load DB drivers myself.

The code is:

```
    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application app){
    System.out.println("IN beforeStart");
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        System.out.println("org.postgresql.Driver LOADED");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println("NOT LOADED org.postgresql.Driver");
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    config.setName("pgtest");

    DataSourceConfig postgresDb = new DataSourceConfig ();
    postgresDb.setDriver("org.postgresql.Driver");
    postgresDb.setUsername("postgres");
    postgresDb.setPassword("postgrespassword");
    postgresDb.setUrl("postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@localhost:5432/TotoIntegration2");

    config.setDataSourceConfig(postgresDb);
    config.setDefaultServer(true);
    EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);





    SqlQuery countTables = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select count(*) from  pg_stat_user_tables;");

    Integer numTables = countTables.findUnique().getInteger("count");
    System.out.println("numTables = " + numTables);
    if(numTables>2){
        DbHelper.cleanSchema();
    }
    System.out.println("beforeStart EXECUTED");
    //DbHelper.cleanSchema();

}
```

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") passed without exceptions, but then I'm getting:

com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for postgres

on the line EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);

Why?

Comment: Your JDBC url is wrong, it should start with `jdbc:postgresql:` (and the rest of the URL looks wrong as well), see http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/connect.html Also note that JDBC 4 compliant drivers no longer need to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onStart` instead, it's performed right after `beforeStart` but it's natural candidate for operating on database (in production mode it doesn't wait for first request), javadoc for them:

```
/**
 * Executed before any plugin - you can set-up your database schema here, for instance.
 */
public void beforeStart(Application app) {
}

/**
 * Executed after all plugins, including the database set-up with Evolutions and the EBean wrapper.
 * This is a good place to execute some of your application code to create entries, for instance.
 */
public void onStart(Application app) {
}
```

Note, that you don't need include DB config additionally here, you can use your models here the same way as you do in controller.